# How the problem "User matching query does not exist" to solve

Tags: django-views

I want to write a command to register users, but when I fill out the form, I click on the registration option, and the error User matching query does not exist. is showing

This is my code

Note:

I am learning and my teacher himself said that this method of registration is not standard

I wrote the parts related to errors in my own language because English is not my language

error:

```
nternal Server Error: /register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\shop\account\views.py", line 38, in user_register
    if User.objects.get(username=username):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 637, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def user_register(request):
    
    contaxt = {'errors': []}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            password1 = request.POST.get('password1')
            password2 = request.POST.get('password2')

            if password1 != password2:
                contaxt['errors'].append('پسورد مشابه نیست')
                return render(request, 'account/register.html', contaxt)

            if User.objects.get(username=username):
                contaxt['errors'].append('این نام کاربری وجود دارد')
                return render(request, 'account/register.html', contaxt)

            User.objects.create(username=username, email=email, password=password1)
            
            return redirect('/')

        return render(request, 'account/register.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You perform a `get()` on the User model, this results in either a User object or throws an error. If you want to check if a User with that username already exists, you can do:

```py
if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
    # Code here
```